# A Hollow Hole Around The Equator Of A UVSphere

Tags: modeling, mesh, uv

Could someone help me make a straight hole into the [center](https://i.ibb.co/1GtDGNV/Image5.jpg) of my sphere. Like this but into the center of my Sphere. https://i.ibb.co/gj8Xg2h/Image4.jpg

My Sphere - https://i.ibb.co/nmxr92K/Image1.jpg
Wireframe Version Of My Sphere - https://i.ibb.co/9YKyp8S/Image3.jpg

Comment: I don't understand how you would like the hole, could you please make a drawing? Is it supposed to go through the sphere horizontally rather than vertically?

Comment: @moonboots It's kinda hard to explain, here is a sketch of it. Hopefully you can understand... sorry ;-;

Comment: I can't see your sketch, could you please edit your question and display all your images?

Comment: @moonboots I forgot to attach the image, sorry. here it is. https://i.ibb.co/ZMsJzPH/Image6.jpg

Comment: I still don't understand, is it supposed to be a whole going through like the one you show going from north pole to south pole?

Comment: Basically splitting a sphere into 2 but there is a roof i guess, But not in the middle where my hole is in the middle of the sphere.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-Select that inner ring.
-Ctrl-B and drag to desired width.
-E (extrude), S (scale), Ctrl-Shit-Z (so it does not scale to Z axis)
-Done

I hope thats what you needed!

[image]

Comment: Or instead of E, S, Shift+Z simply use Alt+E > _Extrude Along Face Normals_.

Comment: Thanks @XuXo Pereira , Is there a way to remove the part it pushes out and still have the hole along the equator?

Comment: You're welcome. To remove that part just press X (delete) and click -Faces-

Comment: Or press X > _Delete Vertices_ depending on how much you want to delete.